# I need help installing a UEFI boot

Tags: system-installation, 16.04, uefi

Ubuntu installed without errors but the system will not boot to it, says it is not a valid operating system.

Secure boot is off.

The system boots to a different hard drive installed on a non UEFI system.

boot-repair doesn't find any errors, boot-repair report is here: http://paste2.org/CehUbn8B

Comment: Somehow you have MBR(msdos) partitioning with an UEFI system that is normally gpt partitioned.  I might consider converting to gpt, and boot may work or totally reinstall and use gpt partitioning. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu and:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI What model Asus? But I do not know AMD video which may also have issues. If you want to convert: http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html One Asus needed boot parameters: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2312977

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that you MUST user GPT partition table type to make the UEFI System boot. Some time ago,i had the exactly same problem. I solved it, formatting my disk, and creating a new partition table with gParted from the LiveUSB. The default value for the partition table is msdos, which is for Legacy boot. Change to GPT from the dropdown list.

A more detailed process is:

1. Boot from the liveUSB or liveCD in UEFI mode
2. Install gParted from the command prompt or software manager. You can use the following command: `sudo apt-get install gparted`
3. Open gparted
4. Make sure that the selected disk is your hard drive or installation target, for example: `/dev/sda` at the top right corner.
5. Go to Device -> Create Partition Table
6. Select GPT
7. Apply
8. Accept the warning messages and after the changes has been applied, close gparted
9. Open the installation program and select manual install when prompted
10. Create the efi partition at the beggining of the disk with about 250MB
11. Format it as FAT32
12. Continue with the rest of the install process, setting the other partitions and options.

Have fun!

Comment: Excellent!, you can mark this question as solved, and accept my answer. Thanks and enjoy your new installation!